# CRUD operation with pure javascript using mockAPI

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, post, get

I built a pure poc javascript ajax app which has get and post methods to manipulate responses. 
    **Scenarios to be covered:**

```
 1. If I have static JSON data already in webservice on load the GET method should get the response and build a dynamic table accordingly
 2. If I found no data in response I will ask the user to submit their datas to create response with the payload and build table dynamically
 3. If I have already built table and the user wants to submit additional record to add it has to be posted and with that response the new table row has to be inserted.
```

I have buildtable function which handles the dynamic table creation.I have covered two scenarios of getting and posting the data. But when I tried doing third scenario the build table function building the table from the scratch. I want the function to handle the third scenario which should add the specific data row alone in the table instead of creating the entire table again.

Please find the below.

[crud js ajax](https://codepen.io/yogeshkumarasamy/pen/NyyRQv)

Comment: https://codepen.io/yogeshkumarasamy/pen/NyyRQv